# i want to change css of my scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

i want to change my scrollbar design using css. i use this css but it only apply on chrome,

```
<style>

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
</style>
```

tell me how can i change my scrollbar in firefox using css.

thanks in advance

Comment: but it's not full fill my requirements

Comment: You have written for webkit so it only work for chrome and safari. For mozilla firefox till date no css will apply over scrolbarl may be  in next updated version they support it

Comment: so we don't have any option for mozilla ?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change style of scrollbar cross-browser you have to use some (jQuery) plugin. I use this one http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html it is cross-browser compatible and easy to implement.

Also great one is this http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#examples

And here you can find more http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/

Comment: hello @michal is there any way to do this by css only

Comment: there: http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change it in mozilla using CSS put -moz- intead of -webkit-, e.g:

-moz-scrollbar { width: 12px; }

-webkit- works for chrome and safari, -moz- for firefox, -o- for opera, and -ms- for IE.

It seems you have to put all 4 lines to make it work on every browser, e.g:

```
-webkit-scrollbar {width: 12px;}<br/>
-o-scrollbar {width: 12px;}<br/>
-moz-scrollbar {width: 12px;}<br/>
-ms-scrollbar {width: 12px;}<br/>
```